# Resolve a raise-missing-from Pylint exception in CQL query loop

Tags: python, http, exception, python-requests, pylint

How to resolve the following `Pylint` linting error:

```
pylint:W0707:Consider explicitly re-raising using 'raise SystemExit(http_error) from http_error'
```

Here is my code:

```
try:
    for label in labels:
        # CQL query to append label name to url
        self.query = {"cql": f"type=page and label='{label}'"}

        self.response = requests.request(
            "GET",
            self.rest_url,
            auth=BearerAuth(self._token),
            params=self.query,
            timeout=100,
        )
        self.response.raise_for_status()

        #some Code

        return self.page_details

except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_error:
    raise SystemExit(http_error)`
```

I tried simply printing error instead but it will show another lint error because of it.
I am not sure what is the best way to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is telling you what to do: `Consider explicitly re-raising using 'raise SystemExit(http_error) from http_error'`. i.e. do this:

```
    try:
        for label in labels:
            # CQL query to append label name to url
            self.query = {"cql": f"type=page and label='{label}'"}

            self.response = requests.request(
                "GET",
                self.rest_url,
                auth=BearerAuth(self._token),
                params=self.query,
                timeout=100,
            )
            self.response.raise_for_status()

            #some Code

        return self.page_details

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as http_error:
        raise SystemExit(http_error) from http_error
```

Checking the doc could be helpful in general too: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/raise-missing-from.html

Please let me know how I can make the message clearer (I'm the maintainer of the tool raising this message).